# Differences between Push functions in RIM OS (BIS), IOS and android

Tags: android, ios, blackberry, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Can anybody explain the differences between Push function in those OS for me?
I'm really curious about how do they work and how they work differently from others.
As far as I know, android applies Push function by keeping a port always on. How about other OSs?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Push notifications, by definition, all should work with the same concept. As per my understanding, there would be a open port to the server, through which it can receive messages. The finer details might vary a bit, but I believe all of them work with the same principle of keeping a channel open at all times, as long as you have network connectivity.

There are different ways of achieving push notifications. You might want to look at this first.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology

Comment: oh really. Basing on your answer, I think my assumption about RIM OS's Push service (BIS or BES) was wrong. I thought that RIM used some kinds of technology that different than others. I thought BIS/BES servers before they wanted to push anything to the end devices, it would send some kinds of simple signal (mobile signal) so that the device could active the data connection to receive the incoming data (I think it will save energy) .

Comment: RIM pushes also need a port listening on the device. Here you have a link that explains how it works: `http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=ZOInkvkk20U#!`